# what does "Move up-slope" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "***Move up-slope***" mean in this context?

> If near a stream or river, be aware of rising water and possible mudflows in low-lying areas. ***Move up-slope*** as quickly as possible.
>   <sub>Source: [Key Facts About Protecting Yourself During a Volcanic Eruption](http://emergency.cdc.gov/disasters/volcanoes/during.asp), CDC.</sub>

Comment: It means *move uphill*, or *move to higher ground*. You could say it means: *Get out of the ditch!*

Comment: I haven't heard *up-slope* used in this context. We would generally say "move to higher ground". But the meaning is obvious in context.

Comment: @user3169 - I've seen this phrase used on occasion. If you search for `"move up slope"` on Google or Google books, you can find some hits, (like this one, about horseshoe crabs: _By instinct, they move up-slope, out of the sea, onto the beaches;_ or this one, about air movement: _In mountainous terrain there is a tendency for air to move up-slope during the day and to drain down-slope during the night_). Though its meaning may be obvious, it's still quite an unusual (and interesting) wording – one we don't run across very often. I'm hoping someone will talk about it some more in an answer.

Comment: so is there any alternative phrase that has the same meaning and it is commonly used?

Comment: @Maher I don't have a good explanation at the moment, but this might help: think of *up-slope* like *uphill*, e.g. *[The sidestep helps] a skier move uphill or downhill along the fall line through narrow, steep sections of a trail or very deep snow where no other technique is possible.* It's just that *up-slope* has a wider range of use because the slope doesn't have to be a hill.

Comment: It's often stated as: *Move to higher ground*

Answer (score 1):

In this context, 'up-slope' is a synonym for 'uphill'. The higher you are from the banks of the stream, the less likely any mudflow or flood could overwhelm you.